# can my app get rejected if a tableviewcell doesn't highlight?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am not highlighting my uitableview cells when they are selected, but they contain clickable links which shows a new view. is this ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not. Every game/app has glitches. Just because they do not light up will not get your app rejected. You still might want to fix it though.

Look at this:

[WWDC 2010: Steve Jobs on the App Store](http://digitaldaily.allthingsd.com/20100607/wwdc-2010-steve-jobs-on-the-app-store/?mod=appletablet)

Your app will only get rejected for three reasons:

> 1: The app doesn’t do what you said it
>   would.
>
> 2: It uses private APIs…and if they
>   change the app will break.
>
> And the third reason? They crash.”

Just as long as your app is not doing/using any of those things your fine.

Comment: Just because Steve Jobs says, doesn't make it so, there are a plethora of other reasons for while your app could get rejected, Porn, Trademark, "Duplicating Functionality", etc, but this discussion is neither here nor there.

To the question asker:

I recommend reading the HIG and adhering to it as much as possible: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

Obviously there can be some divergence, but generally you want to make the app as easy as possible (for the reviewer) to use.

Comment: Steve didn't say that anyway. He said those were the three most common reasons.

Comment: Either way, he still isn't going to get his app rejected for the tableview not lighting up.